# Swift pageViewController activated by button

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In the main view controller I have one simple button that activated one `pageViewController`. This `pageViewController` contain two view controllers.

I am trying to activate it but it doesn't work.

the code in the file `pageviewcontroller` is:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var myViewControllers : [UIViewController] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let p1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("a") as aViewController
        let p2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("b") as bViewController

        myViewControllers = [p1,p2]


        for var index = 0; index < myViewControllers.count; ++index {
            NSLog("\(myViewControllers[index])")
        }

        let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
        let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]

        self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: {(done: Bool) in
        })

        NSLog("loaded!");

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Private Function
    func viewControllerAtIndex (index: NSInteger) -> UIViewController{
        return myViewControllers[index]
    }

    //Delegates and Datasource
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        NSLog("Entered to BeforeViewController")

        var index = find(myViewControllers, viewController)!
        NSLog("\(index)")
        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }
        index--
        if index == myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        NSLog("\(index)")
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

         NSLog("Entered to BeforeViewController")

        var index = find(myViewControllers, viewController)!
        NSLog("\(index)")
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }
        index++
        if index == myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        NSLog("\(index)")
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return myViewControllers.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

The code in the view controller included in the pageviewcontroller is :

```
import UIKit

class aViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

When I push the button appear this error:

```
2015-02-05 20:37:21.111 Tutorial-JSON-Alamofire[616:165935] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x1452de40>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'a''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x21a4a49f 0x2f204c8b 0x2545ea09 0x107130 0x1085e4 0x24f0b52f 0x24f0b29d 0x255645d5 0x251d4ead 0x251ece21 0x251eedb7 0x24feb2ef 0x251f1815 0x25304321 0x24f3c21b 0x24f3c1c1 0x24f26e33 0x24f3bc2d 0x24f3b907 0x24f351d1 0x24f0b97d 0x2517f2e9 0x24f0a3d9 0x21a10d57 0x21a10167 0x21a0e7cd 0x2195c3c1 0x2195c1d3 0x28d5a0a9 0x24f6a7b1 0x10dd60 0x10dd9c 0x2f784aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the given Exception:

The identifier you are using to retrieve UIViewController reference does not belong to any in StoryBoard. You need to change the storyboard id to "a".

**Update**

- Select your viewcontroller from storyboard.
- Select Identity inspector (third from the left) from Utilities (top right).
- Enter the identifier there.

[image]

Comment: How I can do this from the storyboard?

Comment: @RenzoG Take a look at this.